# A new session could not be created exception occurs

Tags: appium

i will try to open chrome browser & automate the facebook (try to open any site so that i can check my appium configuration is ok or not)

After execution of following code got exception as,

```
@Test
public void test1() throws MalformedURLException
{
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.android();
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, BrowserType.CHROME);
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM, Platform.ANDROID);
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "my phone");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.VERSION, "6.0.1");

    URL url=new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4727/wd/hub");
    //java.net.URL url=new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4727/wd/hub");

    //URL url=new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4727/wd/hub");

    WebDriver driver=new AndroidDriver(url, capabilities);
    //WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL( http://****:4723/wd/hub), capabilities);
    //  WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://****:4723/wd/hub", capabilities);
    //driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com"); 
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
```

exception as,

```
@BeforeTest setUp org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. (Original error: unknown error: Device 4e89be7c is not online (Driver info: chromedriver=2.18.343845 (73dd713ba7fbfb73cbb514e62641d8c96a94682a),platform=Windows NT 10.0 x86_64))) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 9.05 seconds Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'
```

please help

Comment: From appium docs: Make sure that your device can connect to ADB and has Developer Mode enabled. For testing Chrome on a real device, you’re responsible for ensuring that Chrome of an appropriate version is installed.

Also, you’ll want to make sure that “Verify Apps” in settings is disabled/unchecked, otherwise it can prevent some of Appium’s helper apps from launching and doing their job correctly.

Comment: i have rechecked above all possible cases.

Answer (score 1):

I see in the stacktrace that "Device 4e89be7c is not online"

I'm pretty sure that you avd is open and running so please time in terminal "adb devices"

if your avd is shown and its status is "offline" then type:
"adb kill-server"

IMPORTANT: Close any instances of adb in the Task Manager

now type in terminal "adb start-server" and "adb devices" -> if the status of the adb has changed, you are good to go.

Comment: adb devices
List of devices attached
4e89be7c        device  means device is ok & connected.

Comment: @Chetan even if the device is offline and connected, adb devices will list your device. However, appium server will start only if the device is in online state. Try restarting the adb server as David mentioned. It should work.